# How to create a string attribute when using weka java API in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, weka

I want to write mat data to an arff file for Weka in Matlab. I don't know how to create a string attribute when using Weka API although I understood the [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639802/creating-a-string-attribute-in-weka-java-api). The problem is how to implement the following in Matlab:

```
FastVector attributes = new FastVector();
attributes.addElement(new Attribute("attr", (FastVector) null));
```

Does anyone know how to do the above in Matlab? thanks

Answer (score -1):

There is a little bit of odd syntax when connecting matlab and java, for instance:

- the `new` keyword is non-existant.
- use single quotes for strings.

This boils down to knowing how to call java from matlab, for which there are plenty of examples:

[[1]](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/ECC/javaMatlab.html) 
[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520503/calling-java-from-matlab) 
[[3]](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/techdoc/matlab_external/ch_java.html)
[[4]](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html)

In any case, for you the solution would be something along the lines of:

```
import weka.core.FastVector;
import weka.core.Attribute;

fv = FastVector();
attr = Attribute('attr',FastVector());
fv.addElement(attr);
```

Note, this code hasn't been tested as I don't currently have WEKA installed.

Comment: This does not work. Weka needs a null casted to FastVector for this to work.