# Classifying Single Instance in Weka using Java

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, weka

I trained and created a Nativebases using WEKA gui. I saved the model file to my computer and now I would like to use it to classify a single instance in my Java code. I would like to get a prediction for the attribute "cluster". What I do is the following:

```
package level_4_project_weka;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.DenseInstance;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;

 public class wekaClass2 {



 private Instance inst_co;



 String classify(
        float area_of_disease1,
        float length_of_disease1,
        int s_area_count1, 
        float sd_disease_r1, 
        float sd_disease_g1, 
        float sd_disease_b1, 
        float sd_background_r1, 
        float sd_background_g1, 
        float sd_background_b1, 
        int m_disease_r1, 
        int m_disease_g1, 
        int m_disease_b1, 
        int m_background_r1, 
        int m_background_g1, 
        int m_background_b1, 
        String fluid_filled_blisters1, 
        String feel_itchy1) {

    String result = null;
    try {

        ArrayList<Attribute> attributeList = new ArrayList<>(17);

        Attribute area_of_disease = new Attribute("area_of_disease");
        Attribute length_of_disease = new Attribute("length_of_disease");
        Attribute s_area_count = new Attribute("s_area_count");
        Attribute sd_disease_r = new Attribute("sd_disease_r");
        Attribute sd_disease_g = new Attribute("sd_disease_g");
        Attribute sd_disease_b = new Attribute("sd_disease_b");
        Attribute sd_background_r = new Attribute("sd_background_r");
        Attribute sd_background_g = new Attribute("sd_background_g");
        Attribute sd_background_b = new Attribute("sd_background_b");
        Attribute m_disease_r = new Attribute("m_disease_r");
        Attribute m_disease_g = new Attribute("m_disease_g");
        Attribute m_disease_b = new Attribute("m_disease_b");
        Attribute m_background_r = new Attribute("m_background_r");
        Attribute m_background_g = new Attribute("m_background_g");
        Attribute m_background_b = new Attribute("m_background_b");
        Attribute fluid_filled_blisters = new Attribute("fluid_filled_blisters");
        Attribute feel_itchy = new Attribute("feel_itchy");

        ArrayList<String> classVal = new ArrayList<>();
        classVal.add("melanoma");
        classVal.add("eczema");
        classVal.add("impetigo");
        //classVal.add("ClassB");


        attributeList.add(area_of_disease);
        attributeList.add(length_of_disease);
        attributeList.add(s_area_count);
        attributeList.add(sd_disease_r);
        attributeList.add(sd_disease_g);
        attributeList.add(sd_disease_b);
        attributeList.add(sd_background_r);
        attributeList.add(sd_background_g);
        attributeList.add(sd_background_b);
        attributeList.add(m_disease_r);
        attributeList.add(m_disease_g);
        attributeList.add(m_disease_b);            
        attributeList.add(m_background_r);
        attributeList.add(m_background_g);
        attributeList.add(m_background_b);
        attributeList.add(fluid_filled_blisters);
        attributeList.add(feel_itchy);

        attributeList.add(new Attribute("@@type@@",classVal));

        Instances data = new Instances("TestInstances",attributeList,0);


        // Create instances for each pollutant with attribute values latitude,
        // longitude and pollutant itself
        inst_co = new DenseInstance(data.numAttributes());
        data.add(inst_co);

        // Set instance's values for the attributes "latitude", "longitude", and
        // "pollutant concentration"
         inst_co.setValue(area_of_disease,area_of_disease1);
         inst_co.setValue(length_of_disease,length_of_disease1);
         inst_co.setValue(s_area_count,s_area_count1);
         inst_co.setValue(sd_disease_r,sd_disease_r1);
         inst_co.setValue(sd_disease_g,sd_disease_g1);
         inst_co.setValue(sd_disease_b,sd_disease_b1);
         inst_co.setValue(sd_background_r,sd_background_r1);
         inst_co.setValue(sd_background_g,sd_background_g1);
         inst_co.setValue(sd_background_b,sd_background_b1);
         inst_co.setValue(m_disease_r,m_disease_r1);
         inst_co.setValue(m_disease_g,m_disease_g1);
         inst_co.setValue(m_disease_b,m_disease_b1);            
         inst_co.setValue(m_background_r,m_background_r1);
         inst_co.setValue(m_background_g,m_background_g1);
         inst_co.setValue(m_background_b,m_background_b1);
         inst_co.setValue(fluid_filled_blisters,fluid_filled_blisters1);
         inst_co.setValue(feel_itchy,feel_itchy1);
        // inst_co.setMissing(cluster);

        // load classifier from file
        Classifier cls_co = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper
                .read("C:/Users/Lahiru/Documents/NetBeansProjects/level_4_project_weka/diseases.model");

       double result1 = cls_co.classifyInstance(inst_co);
        System.out.println("a" + result1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return result;
   }


   }
```

but when I add the

```
        `inst_co.setValue(fluid_filled_blisters,fluid_filled_blisters1);
         inst_co.setValue(feel_itchy,feel_itchy1);`
```

I got the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute neither nominal nor string!
at weka.core.AbstractInstance.setValue(AbstractInstance.java:518)
at level_4_project_weka.wekaClass2.classify(wekaClass2.java:112)
at   level_4_project_weka.Level_4_project_weka.PredictDisease(Level_4_project_weka.java:102)
at level_4_project_weka.Level_4_project_weka.main(Level_4_project_weka.java:27)
```

I know, this error occur because of these two are string varibles. but I don't know how to deal with string. Can anyone show me correct way to do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating a string attribute in weka java API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639802/creating-a-string-attribute-in-weka-java-api)

Answer (score 0):

See the Weka documentation:

http://weka.wikispaces.com/Creating+an+ARFF+file

which details how to create Attributes with proper type information.

See also:
[creating a string attribute in weka java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639802/creating-a-string-attribute-in-weka-java-api)

Comment: No it is not . because I also saw this link but it is an old way to do this. with weka.jar new version it shoes FastVactors as depreciate. So this why i put this question here to get new answer. Thank for the answer. I'm looking forward better ona

Comment: What does the new Weka jar suggest to use otherwise? (it's still the same question then, though... only needs an updated answer...)

Comment: (As far as I can tell, it still works the same way; except that you can also use `ArrayList` instead of `FastVector`...)