# How do you copy a dataset's class values in weka?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I have two `Instances` datasets: `data` is the original and `stumpyInsts` is the one I am trying to copy the class values to. Here is my code:

```
FastVector attributes = new FastVector();
ArrayList<Instance> instances = new ArrayList<Instance>();
for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
    Attribute newAttr = new Attribute("Stump" + i, i);
    attributes.addElement(newAttr);
}
//make new instances
Instances stumpyInsts = new Instances("Stumps", attributes, data.numInstances());

stumpyInsts.setClassIndex(stumpyInsts.numAttributes() - 1);
Enumeration instEnum = stumpyInsts.enumerateInstances();
Enumeration somethingElseLOL = data.enumerateInstances();
while (instEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
    Instance instance = (Instance) instEnum.nextElement();
    Instance other = (Instance) somethingElseLOL.nextElement();
    String s = other.stringValue(other.classIndex());
    instance.setValue(instance.classIndex(), s);
}
```

I keep getting this when I try to set the value:

```
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute neither nominal nor string!
at weka.core.Instance.setValue(Instance.java:687)`
```

Does anyone know why it happens? I also get the error if I try to `setClassValue` before adding the instance to the dataset, or if I make new strings with those values. To me it doesn't really make sense, since `stringValue` is clearly returning a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute neither nominal nor string!
  at weka.core.Instance.setValue(Instance.java:687)
```

does not refer to `stringValue`, but to the class attribute of `instance`. When you do

```
stumpyInsts.setClassIndex(stumpyInsts.numAttributes() - 1);
```

you tell `stumpyInsts` what index its class is, but not that is should be a nominal or String attribute. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639802/creating-a-string-attribute-in-weka-java-api) you would have to do something like

```
FastVector classAttr = new FastVector();
classAttr .addElement(new Attribute("class", (FastVector) null));
```

to create a (class) attribute that has string or nominal values.

Comment: I added the previous part of my code and as I was copy-pasting it I saw where my mistake was. Thanks.

Comment: Did my edit describe your solution? If not, it would be nice of you to include it here, so that other with the same problem can be helped.

Comment: Almost. I made a separate `FastVector labels` and added the two class labels to it, then used it for the class attribute. But thanks, your original answer helped me.