# JRuby equivalent for casting null to class

Tags: java, jruby, weka

I try to use the Java weka machine learning lib through JRuby. It works fine so far, there is only one thing I'm wondering:

In order to create a *string* Attribute, you can use the same contructor as for *nominal* Attributes in Java, but with the second parameter being a null casted to FastVector:

```
Attribute attribute = new Attribute("name", (FastVector) null);
```

Also see [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6640193) and the [weka doc for Attribute](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Attribute.html#Attribute(java.lang.String,%20java.util.List)).

In JRuby, if you try to pass just `nil`, e.g.:

```
java_import 'weka.core.Attribute'
attribute = Attribute.new('name', nil)
```

it will raise a `Java::JavaLang::NullPointerException` error.

The full stack trace is:

```
Java::JavaLang::NullPointerException: 
from weka.core.Attribute.<init>(weka/core/Attribute.java:303)
from weka.core.Attribute.<init>(weka/core/Attribute.java:290)
from java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java/lang/reflect/Constructor.java:423)
from RUBY.<eval>((irb):7)
from org.jruby.RubyKernel.eval(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:978)
from org.jruby.RubyKernel.loop(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1291)
from org.jruby.RubyKernel.catch(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1098)
from org.jruby.RubyKernel.catch(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1098)
from Users.pgoetze.$_dot_rvm.rubies.jruby_minus_9_dot_0_dot_1_dot_0.bin.irb.<top>(/Users/pgoetze/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.1.0/bin/irb:13)
from java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.java:627)
```

**Is there a way to create a null vector in JRuby, that can be passed as the second argument instead of the `nil`?**

If not, what might be the way to create a string Attribute?

Comment: Is there a stack trace beside `Java::JavaLang::NullPointerException`?

Comment: I added the full stack trace for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [JRuby wiki states](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#) you are supposed to use reflection to obtain a reference to a constructor specifying types of its arguments.

```
java_import java.util.List
java_import weka.core.Attribute
#...
constructor = Attribute.java_class.declared_constructor(java.lang.String, java.util.List)
attribute = constructor.new_instance('name', nil)
```

Notes:

- `weka.core.FastVector` is just an extension of `ArrayList`
- `weka.core.Attribute` contains [a constructor with single `String` argument](https://github.com/bnjmn/weka/blob/master/weka/src/main/java/weka/core/Attribute.java#L172) which maybe does what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks, using reflection and creating the attribute from the explicit constructor works! You can’t use the constructor with just the single String argument though, because the created Attribute is handled as a *nominal* attribute by Weka internally.